# nuxt.js add css file

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've created nuxt project
`vue init nuxt/starter <project-name>`

In my `nuxt.config.js` I added this:

```
css: [
        { src: '~assets/css/style.css', lang: 'css' }
    ]
```

and in my assets/css folder I have style.css
with

```
body {
    background: black!important;
}
```

But nothing happens with no errors on console. what to I do?

Comment: I just tested and it works fine me...
What version of Nuxt do you use ?

Answer (score 9):

you must add to nuxt.config.js

```
build: {
        extractCSS: true
    }
```

For example,

```
css: [
        { src: '~assets/css/style.css', lang: 'css' }
    ],
build: {
            extractCSS: true
        }
```

And use nuxt v0.10.6

Comment: This is what I was looking for! However, where in the documentation is written about `extractCSS`? Please indicate to me.

Comment: @abdulmanov.ilmir https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#extractcss